# Problem with footnote

Tags: footnotes

hello dears It seems that there is a problem with footnote while having multi column footnote.
when I click the footnotes hyperlink, it brings me to the first page rather than footnote point.
Also its order is not so beautiful. Is there any way to sort it in a better order?
I use Persian language.
The file is as large as 40 tex line 6 pdf line

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pagebackref=false,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=magenta]{hyperref}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{xepersian}
\settextfont{B Titr}[Scale=1,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant]
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}
\baselineskip=.75cm
\begin{document}
\twocolumnfootnotes 
\lr{First Footnote}
\RTLfootnote{زیرنویس اول}
\\
زیرنویس دوم
\LTRfootnote{Second Footnote}
\\
\newpage
زیرنویس سوم 
\LTRfootnote
{
    Third Footnote
}
\\
\lr
{
    Forth Footnote
}
\RTLfootnote
{
زیرنویس چهارم
}\\
زیرنویس پنجم
\RTLfootnote
{
زیر نویس پنجم
}\\
زیرنویس ششم
\LTRfootnote{sixth Footnote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! Please provide a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: `hyperref` is known to be weak with links to footnotes.

Comment: I had added the minimal code but I was not aware that this site does not allow shortened link

Comment: @egreg so which package would you introduce me?

Comment: @GhomarbazGhomarbazian None, without a minimal example. Here, not in some external site.

Comment: @egreg I hadnt understand your lasr sentence. I have provided the MWE.

Comment: Don't put a link to an example. Copy the code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

> when I click the footnotes hyperlink, it brings me to the first page rather than footnote point.

Move `\twocolumnfootnotes` before `\begin{document}`.

> Also its order is not so beautiful. Is there any way to sort it in a better order?

Not sure what you mean here. unless you say what layout you are after, your comment makes no sense.

Comment: what if I like to make footnotes back into 1 column? about the order I meant to place the footnotes in row in two columns rather than ordering in column.

Comment: The best person and I guess the only person who could answer your first question is the author of xepersian package. For your second question, I think you need to use \paragraphfootnotes instead \twocolumnfootnotes (see the bidi package manual)

Comment: it seems that he understood the bug and cleared it

Comment: @GhomarbazGhomarbazian: Not a bug as egreg commented that `hyperref` is known to be weak with links to footnotes.

Comment: So which package would you prefer to use for linking?

Comment: @GhomarbazGhomarbazian: `hyperref` is the only package in LaTeX for linking I am aware of. You do not get it, do you?